# Treemap Onclick d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How to get the value of a rectangle from `treemap` while on click using d3.js?
HTML body is as follows,

```
<g class="depth">
    <g>
        <title>"ABC"</title>
        <g>"My rectangle tag here"</g>
    </g>
    <g>
        <title>"DEF"</title>
        <g>"My rectangle tag here"</g>
    </g>
</g>
```

I want to access the title tag value once I click the rectangle.

Comment: Actually value means the content in the title tag. The rectangles are created dynamically. I have created a sample code in the fiddle.

Comment: Try to explain step-by-step what you want to do, and what results you expect. i.e. what is displayed, what you click and what happens next (like message pops up, next page opens, value gets passed into a script etc)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/103kj49z/2/

Comment: I want to get the text in the title tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using D3, you can select one rectangle on click and get the `title` this way (regarding the *specific SVG structure* you provide in your question):

```
d3.selectAll("rect").on("click", function(){
  var title = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0];
  console.log(title);
});
```

The value of the tag title is stored in `var title`. Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/ow9a0vzd/

Comment: I think you are complicating answer by using core javascript :).  You can use d3 selectors or jquery selectors

Answer (score 1):

Short and sweet

```
d3.selectAll('rect').on('click', function() {
  var title = d3.select(this.parentNode.nextElementSibling).text();
});
```

if title element is before the rect element then use

```
var title = d3.select(this.parentNode.previousElementSibling).text();
```

Use d3 selectors and text function to get the value you want

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/103kj49z/5/)

Comment: But doesn't work. In the OP structure, the rects are inside groups, and the titles are outside the groups.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado it is working you can check the fiddle

Comment: Yes, I see and I agree it's a great solution! It's the "D3 way". But it doesn't work for the specific SVG structure provided by the OP. That's why I used some pure JS.

Comment: I copied svg structure from the fiddle in the question if he want previous sibling he can use `this.previousElementSibling` @Ranjith

Comment: But look at the fiddle in the question, @murli2308: the OP wants the title, and the title is not a sibling of the rect (i.e., not at the same level of the rects). That's why neither previousElementSibling or nextElementSibling are going to work.

Comment: I agree with you. :-)